# Best way to get multiple variable values or information from a function

Tags: python-3.x, function, input, raspberry-pi, evdev

I am fairly new to python and am attempting to create a custom module that I can import for my raspberry pi using evdev (not that important). My problem is I need a good way to know when a given button is pressed down preferably using True/False. If I was to import this module and use the read_stream() function what would be the easiest way to be able to gather multiple types of inputs. (Just for clarification, the gamepad.read_loop() only returns one value per iteration.

```
from evdev import InputDevice, categorize, ecodes

aBtn = 304
bBtn = 305
xBtn = 307
yBtn = 308

LBmper = 310
RBmper = 311

MenuBtn = 315
WindowBtn = 314
XboxBtn = 316

HorizontalDp = 16
VerticalDp = 17

RightT = 5
LeftT = 2

LeftStickClick = 317
RightStickClick = 318

Ls_X = 0
Ls_Y = 1
Rs_X = 3
Rs_Y = 4

def read_stream(input_path, trigger_deadzone):
    '''Begins the loop that reads all of the incoming events.'''
    button_list = ['aBtn_pressed', 'bBtn_pressed', 'xBtn_pressed', 'yBtn_pressed', 'lBmper_pressed', 'rBmper_pressed', 'mBtn_pressed', 'wBtn_pressed', 'xbxBtn_pressed', 'rDp_pressed', 'lDp_pressed', 'dDp_pressed', 'uDp_pressed', 'Ls_clicked', 'Rs_clicked', 'Ls_right', 'Ls_left', 'Ls_down', 'Ls_up', 'Rs_right', 'Rs_left', 'Rs_down', 'Rs_up', 'Lt_custom', 'Rt_custom']
    for button in button_list:
        button = False
    gamepad = InputDevice(input_path)
    if (not "Microsoft X-Box One S pad" in str(gamepad)):
        raise Exception("Invalid input device, please make sure you are using an Xbox One S controller.\nAlso make sure that the correct input path is set.")
    print("Stream is reading: ", gamepad)
    for event in gamepad.read_loop():
        value = event.value
        code = event.code
        if (code == aBtn):
        #if (304 <= code <= 308):
            if (code == aBtn):
                if (value == 1):
                    aBtn_pressed = True
                else:
                    aBtn_pressed = False
            elif (code == bBtn):
                if (value == 1):
                    bBtn_pressed = True
                else:
                    bBtn_pressed = False
            elif (code == xBtn):
                if (value == 1):
                    xBtn_pressed = True
                else:
                    xBtn_pressed = False
            else:
                if (value == 1):
                    yBtn_pressed = True
                else:
                    yBtn_pressed = False
        else:
            print("Unfiltered stream input.")
```

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to determine exactly what you're asking, but if you'd like the state of each button every time you call that function one way would be to return the current values in a dictionary each time.

For example:

```
buttons = {
   304:"A",
   305:"B",
   307:"X",
   308:"Y" )

# and then your read stream function would be modified to look like

pressed = dict()
for event in gamepad.read_loop():
   btn = buttons[event.code]
   pressed[btn] = bool(event.value)
return pressed
```